# Does awaiting a non-Promise have any effect on performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, event-loop

Lets say I have this function

```
function sendMessage(message, content) {
  return message.send(content);
}
```

message returns a promise, but I don't actually need to resolve the promise as I don't care for the returned value.

In another async function, I call sendMessage as follows:

```
await sendMessage(message, 'Hello')
```

vs

```
return sendMessage(message, 'Hello')
```

The async function which am I calling this in is being awaited at the top level.

My question is what is the difference between me await vs returning, as the sendMessage function is not async and I don't need the returned value. What would be faster in terms of a more efficient for performance and event loop speed, if at all there even is a difference? Thanks!

Comment: I believe the promise returned by message.send() gets resolved/rejected in send() method's implementation.. if you don't want to use the result you can very well skip the results. It won't affect the event loop in any case(res/rej/ or left in pending).. but I suggest you to attach atleast an catch handler just to avoid unexpected error s.

Comment: Well one thing I left out is, the function I am calling sendMessage in, is async, and that is being awaited at the top level. So I don't know whether it makes a difference to await or return since at the top level it's still async/await

Comment: Yes, I do a have a .catch() on the message.send(), but in my next function, does it make any difference using return vs await? or it makes absolutely no difference

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*I don't actually need to resolve the promise*". It's `message.send` that resolves the promise it returns, not you. All you can do is wait for it (or not wait for it).

Comment: The performance will be dominated by the time the actual message sending takes. The number of event loop ticks is absolutely insignificant (and also subject to further engine optimisations). Write the code that is correct and clear.

Comment: What's wrong if I use nested/chaining promise handle?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a performance difference between the two; If you don't need use the value of the resolved promise, you shouldn't be using `return` or `await`.

Answer (score 0):

As [mozilla official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) mentioned:

> An async function is a function declared with the async keyword, and the await keyword is permitted within it. The async and await keywords enable asynchronous, promise-based behavior to be written in a cleaner style, avoiding the need to explicitly configure promise chains.

> The body of an async function can be thought of as being split by zero or more await expressions. Top-level code, up to and including the first await expression (if there is one), is run synchronously. In this way, an async function without an await expression will run synchronously. If there is an await expression inside the function body, however, the async function will always complete asynchronously.

On the other word, we usually use `async` functions and `await` keyword mostly to avoid promise chaining (`promise.then()` multiple times, which make our code really messy and unreadable) when running multiple promises synchronously. Since your code contained only one promise only, basicly `await`-ing the promise to fullfil or return it directly will be the same.

Answer (score -3):

async/await just is syntactic sugar,await need use with async otherwise it will throw a error,and it will transform it to a promise,promise are async non-promise are sync,it will affect thread execute order.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).